# How do you make your project available so you can use the OnOff trait with google assistant on raspberry pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, google-assistant-sdk

Sorry if I do something wrong, I'm new to this website.  I was directed here after asking the following question to google support.

I've downloaded the google assistant onto my raspberry pi and I'm following the instructions as found on your services pages (https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python). I've made it to the part where its walking you through turning on an LED wired to your raspberry pi. I activated the "oneoff" trait but it doesn't appear like its working. When I ask my google assistant on my raspberry pi "Turn on" (as the instructions say) it responds, "Sorry, power controls is not yet supported. I've also tried asking it "turn on light". and it responds "The Adjutant isn't available. You might want to try setting it up again." (Adjutant is the name of my project). I've been trying to find the root of the problem, but I have been unsuccessful. I would be much appreciative if you could help me resolve the issue. Let me know if there is any other information that you will need to know to understand the issue.  I'm using a raspberry pi 3B

I've gone through the steps again to see if I missed an important step, but I didn't see one.  I've looked though other support pages, and searched other tutorials, but they were either outdated, or I didn't fully grasp the content.

Thanks a Ton for your help!
Cody

Comment: Can you confirm you [set up the OnOff trait and run that in your command line](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python/extend/register-device-traits)?

Comment: I've gone through those steps.  I've added the onoff trait to my device.  What do you mean by running that in the command line?

Comment: When I run the assistant, I run the following code:( source env/bin/activate)  to activate my environment, and then I run this code: (googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk)

Comment: Are you including your device model id when you run the command?

Comment: I use the model id when I start it with this command: (googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk --project-id my-dev-project --device-model-id my-model). To my understanding, you only have to do that once and then you can just use the first part (googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk)

Comment: You should always provide those parameters

Comment: Alright, will do.  My assistant still doesn't access my onoff trait though

Comment: I do find it weird though, I made a new project, and I inputed that command with the new project-id and new model-id and the output says its using the device model of my other project.

Comment: You need to make sure your auth has also changed.

Comment: What do you mean by that?  I've made made my auth, and I then made a device and then added a trait to that device

Comment: If you use a different project, you will need to follow the steps to reauthorize your project with the google-oauthlib-tool.